# Is there any way to change the control scheme in NFS Most Wanted (Vita)?

Tags: ps-vita, need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

I got *Need For Speed Most Wanted* on the NFS Deals at PSN Plus ($5), and the game is really pretty—as the reviews say.

However, I can't find a way to change the control scheme; not even in the manual. I would prefer to use `X` to accelerate and `□` to brake, as I find the newer `L`/`R` manner that many games are shipping with to be terrible.

Is there a way I can change the controls to fit my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. No such option. You're stuck with the default layout. This is the #1 complaint about the game.